# My attempt at preloading images

Tags: jquery

Ok I nabbed method C for preloading images from this question 
[best way to preload multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761263/what-is-the-best-way-to-preload-multiple-images-in-javascript/761332)
I'm trying to implement it into a get Json array

```
$.getJSON('/pageCall.php',{chapters:chapterNumber}, function(data) 
        {
            chapter=data;
            totalPages = chapter.length;

            var options = '';
            $.each(chapter, function(index, array) {
             images[index] = new Image();
             images[index].src = array['imageLocation'];
});
};
```

but when I try and call the images using the following method nothing appears

```
function callImage(ImageNo)
    {   
        $('#mangaImage').attr('src', images[ImageNo]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's fix some syntax errors, (missing `)`, and this assumes `chapter` and `totalPages` are variables defined elsewhere already), it should look like this:

```
$.getJSON('/pageCall.php',{chapters:chapterNumber}, function(data) {
   chapter=data;
   totalPages = chapter.length;
   var options = '';
   $.each(chapter, function(index, array) {
      images[index] = new Image();
      images[index].src = array['imageLocation'];
   });
});
```

Note that this also assumes a structure like this:

```
[{"imageLocation": "url.jpg"},{"imageLocation": "url.jpg"}]
```

....if it's different, the loop will be different.

---

Also, what's in your array is an image, not a string...so you need to get the `.src` property from it.  Instead of this:

```
$('#mangaImage').attr('src', images[ImageNo]);
```

It should be:

```
$('#mangaImage').attr('src', images[ImageNo].src);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `)` on the last line of the first script.

Change

```
};
```

To

```
});
```

;) - that's a wink