# Should we still preload mouseover images?

Tags: html

A designer just gave me the HTML/JS/CSS for a new site design.  The page is using the good old fashioned MM_crap methods to preload images.

Should we still be preloading mouseover images in today's world?  It feels so 1998.

Comment: Ideally you should be using [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Comment: True - That might be less work too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should we still be preloading mouseover images in today's world?

Yes, absolutely. Even on fast connections, DNS lookups or connection hiccups can create a notable delay when loading an image. You don't want that on a mouseover.

No need to use  Dreamweaver's preload code though: See [What is the best way to preload multiple images in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761263/what-is-the-best-way-to-preload-multiple-images-in-javascript) for alternatives.

Plus, there is a very interesting alternative of course (as mentioned by @hd and @Marcel): [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). Depending on your situation, they can be a superior solution - if you're working on something new, it may well be worth the switch.

Comment: Pekka,i know it is not where to ask my question,but i can ask anymore question here,stackoverflow gives the message that my questions don't meet the standard quality. :(

Comment: @hd see [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997) for some help on that.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it answered the question at hand, even though I'm actually going to use CSS sprites instead of rollover images as @hd suggested.

Answer (score 2):

yes,why use preload mouseover images when we can use CSS sprites?