# How do you attach many images to a javascript array from the server?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I have a website with 500+ icons. I have found that simply letting them load on their own via img.src = "/images/icon1.png" takes far too long and other elements on my site that are further down in the page take like 30 seconds to load due to all the icons loading first. What is the best way to work with a high amount of icons like this? How would you preload it, and preferably not making it into one large sprite! Ideally i would like to server side initialize them into a javascript variable so they can be reused on the client side

Comment: `img.src = "/images/icon1.png"` ← is that javascript or html?

Comment: javascript. At the DOM level. Within a javascript function

Comment: You can lazy load the images. https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload

Comment: You could also group them in several  smaller category sprites and optimize the image through a https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin
or lazy load them as previously mentioned

Comment: "preferably not making it into one large sprite" - Well, that *is* the answer. Otherwise, you'll have 500 HTTP requests, no matter how you manage them.

Comment: hmmm.. Ok ill look into it. Could you reccommend one of the best php sprite generators?

Answer (score 0):

You can preload those images in javascript using:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "/images/icon1.png";
```

A better method is to use an array like so:

```
var preloader = ["a.png", "b.jpg", "c.gif"];

var img = [];

for (i = 0; i < preloader.length; i++) {
    img[i] = new Image();
    img[i].src = preloader[i];
}
```

Check out these posts:

[The definitive best way to preload images using JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901677/the-definitive-best-way-to-preload-images-using-javascript-jquery)

[JavaScript Preloading Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images)

[What is the best way to preload multiple images in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761263/what-is-the-best-way-to-preload-multiple-images-in-javascript/761332)